# What do I say to make a new line when using voice recognition?

Tags: voice-recognition

I've found I can make punctuation happen by saying "comma", or "period", but I can't find the word for new line.  I tried "paragraph", and "line break", but it just prints those words.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found that saying `period newline` gives you a new line, after putting a period on the current line.
Also `period new paragraph` work.

Comment: I've upgraded to Android 4.3 since I asked this question, and this answer seems correct.  `period newline` and `period new paragraph` both work.

Comment: I can confirm this works on Moto X running Android 4.4.2.

Comment: I am running Moto-X and for me "Full stop, new line" works.

Comment: Things must have changed again, because none of these suggestions work anymore.

Answer (score 9):

In Android 4.0, say "New Paragraph"

Answer (score 3):

For Android 4.1.1, I just say "Enter" and it will start a new line.

Answer (score 3):

I said "newline" really fast and it did it on Jelly Bean 4.1.  When I said "new line" slower it filled in the words "new line."  I guess you just say it quick.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "period newline" & "newline" works, but **timing is everything** in this.

**Ex: How to get 3 carriage returns (*2 more below the end of your line*)**: At the last word in your sentence, either say "period newline" or pause and say "new line".

Then for each additional carriage return/line feed you want, **as soon as you see the blinking line move to the next line**, say "newline" and it will give you another, and so forth.

Comment: A lot of the comments in this question helped the light go off, but this was a big one for me. I found that "period new line" works right away, but sometimes I am making a brief sentence fragment of a note, so I don't say period. In that case, I have to wait one second before saying "new line."

Answer (score 1):

I use ColorNote to make a grocery list.  If you say for example "bacon new line", then that will be printed on whatever line the cursor is on, i.e. "bacon new line".  The cursor will not go to the new line.

But, if you say "new line bacon", the cursor moves to a new line and puts the word "bacon" on that new line.  Now, if you say "new line sugar", the cursor will go to the next line and place the word "sugar" on that line.

You have to first say "new line" and then immediately say what you want on that line.
In fact, if you say "new line newline", the cursor will advance two lines, "new line new line newline", the cursor advances 3 lines.

So, know what you want to put on the next line, and start saying it immediately after you say "new line".

Just saying "new line" without any more words will not advance to the next line.  In fact, it will print the words "new line" at the current cursor position.  You must say whatever you want to appear on the new line immediately after saying "new line". Then it works every time.  Found this out by trial and error experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: "Next"

long (and more reliable) answer:

1. Select G-Board as your keyboard device
2. touch the microphone icon
3. After the touch, you can see a circled question mark at the far left of the screen at the same line of the microphone icon, touch the circled question mark.
4. It shows a help page and lists all voice commands, such as "Send", "Stop", ... etc.   The command to "enter" the next line is "Next", according to the help page.

Answer (score 0):

Say, "period new line" in Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Saying "period newline". This works on my Samsung 10.

So when you are done with your sentence and you want to end it with a "period" and have the cursor move to a new line, make sure you say.

As you can see by the formatting of my last sentence, it put a period and brought me to a new line.

Comment: So you are saying you "dictated" this answer, and that "period newline" are the keywords for the action? Why didn't that trigger on your very first line yielding "Saying." only? Is there a time trigger too, so it has to be said quickly together?

Comment: There is no time limit to say it, other than how long your speech to text button turns off, if you don't speak. Yes, you are correct when you asked if I,  "dictated" this answer, and that "period newline" are the keywords for the action? The reason why it didn't trigger on my very first line yielding "Saying" is because I chose not to use that command, because that's the way I wanted to structure my answer. I hope this helps answer your questions and if I misunderstood anything let me know and I will try and clarify for you.

Answer (score 0):

With Android 12 + Google Pixel 6 + Gboard voice typing: the voice command is "New line".

Answer (score -1):

Without any punctuation at the end of what I say, I can just pause and say

"New line" and my Droid X goes to the next line.