# "New line" using Android voice input

Tags: keyboard, 4.3-jelly-bean, voice-recognition

My quetion is - how I can enter "new line" symbol using android voice input?
For example I tyr to create shopping list using Evernote and voice, but to create new item in list I must switch to keybord, and press enter. How to do that using only my voice?

Comment: Have you tried "Eggs Enter Bacon Enter Milk"?

Comment: @JeffreyLin sure. I got "Eggs enter bacon enter milk" as result

Comment: Have you tried the answers [in this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12639/what-do-i-say-to-make-a-new-line-when-using-voice-recognition)?

Comment: Yes, it's not work. Maybe it happens because I have installed 4.3