# Voice typing -how to continue dictation in new line without restarting microphone?

Tags: gboard

The solution in accepted answer here works on Nougat 7.1.2 using Gboard

[What do I say to make a new line when using voice recognition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12639/131553)

But irritatingly, microphone switches off when you move to new line or paragraph and you need to activate it again, breaking the dictation and thought flow

**How to prevent that on Nougat 7.1.2 ( not rooted)?**

Please don't suggest any apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just simply say `enter`, as the <kbd>enter</kbd> key on the keyboard is responsible for adding a new line, same works with speech recognition.

I came across this thing when I needed to type a message on WhatsApp and the enter key was replaced by an emoji key. I tried this trick and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

How to get a new line with voice typing in Android. This works with a Samsung Galaxy A51

1 Before activating voice typing icon press enter on phone keyboard several times bringing the cursor right down the page.

2 Activate Voice typing, Starting as normal at top of page.

3 When requiring new line or paragraph, just touch down below line with finger and proceed.